# How to place ListView scroll bar in margin like Holo style?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I read the Android Developers website and notice that the ListView should have 16dp padding between the list and the screen edge and I notice that the scroll bar of the ListView should be placed inside the padding area. I tried to add paddingLeft and paddingRight to my fragment layout but the scroll bar didn't place inside the padding. How to make my ListView looks like the other ListViews in the system?

Comment: you can try to make the scrollbar invisible

Comment: can you provide a link to the page of the Android developers website where your read this?

Comment: [Metrics and Grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html)

Comment: What I did
http://i.imgur.com/41PJoMn.png

What I want the scroll bar looks like
http://i.imgur.com/P9dDSUY.png

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
```

on your ListView XML.